# iframe align="middle" for image not working

Tags: html, css, angularjs, iframe

I have a form with data populated dynamically. The form is in iframe.
Problem is the form is coming in left of the webpage. I am trying to align it to center of the page. When i did padding-left:13%, it moved to center but when i reduced screen resolution, form came with scroll bar with 13% empty on its left.
I also used iframe align="middle" even then the data is not aligning in center.

```
<div align="center" ng-show="viewForm" style="width:100%">
    <iframe ng-if="formType=='formABC'" style="height: 429px;width:100%" align="middle" src="{{'claims/ClaimView/formABC.html}}"></iframe>
</div>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the css class or id and use this to center anything:

```css
idOrClass{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  }
```

Comment: it is not working. the form is still floating in left

Comment: try this:
position: relative;